# Is there a way to make a button redirect to the page of the current link, but in another language

Tags: javascript, html, replace, hyperlink, html-input

Hello I have 2 blogs in two different languages. All links are identical except the fact that the English blog has a "-en" suffix after the blog name, while the Greek blog has a "-el" suffix.

I want to place a button somewhere that uses the link of the current page. For example "https://cookwithnick-en.blogspot.com/2021/07/mini-piroshki.html", converts it to "https://cookwithnick-el.blogspot.com/2021/07/mini-piroshki.html" and opens it on the same tab.

I have managed to make the following code but doesn't work:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=window.location.href.replace("en", "el");" value="Greek" />
```

And while the code works if the ".replace("en", "el");" is missing (it redirects to the exact same page) I want to convert the link to the other language.

Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Comment: Do you have problem yet?

Comment: @Danial No, I followed your advice thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace double quotes with single quotes in `.replace("en", "el")` So:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=window.location.href.replace('en', 'el');" value="Greek" />
```

However, it's better to do like this:

```
<input type="button" id="change-lang" value="Greek" />

<script>
    document.getElementById("change-lang").addEventListener("click", function(){
        location.href=window.location.href.replace('en', 'el');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. Not being "fluent" in HTML, I cannot understand how the second way will work differently. When you say better you mean that the code will have a better result or that it will not have many errors or it is just better spelling?

Comment: It's not different. It's just best practices @RAPANIS

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes for the strings since the value of the `onclick` attribute is enclosed in double quotes.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=window.location.href.replace('en', 'el');" value="Greek" />
```

However, it is generally better to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline event handlers.

Comment: @NIKOLAOSRAPANIS Glad to help.

Comment: @NIKOLAOSRAPANIS If this solved your issue, consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.